# rvmsudo unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn/production.rb -D --env production is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, unicorn, rvmsudo

I have installed new ec2-instance for production server

when i tried the following command in the current folder

```
    [ec2-user@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx current]$ rvmsudo unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn/production.rb 
    -D --env production

sudo: unicorn_rails: command not found
```

Please let me know how to start the production server which is running at port 80.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you install the gem and its dependencies?

Comment: @apneadiving - yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For port 80: First run

`export rvmsudo_secure_path=1`

then

```
rvmsudo unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn/production.rb -D --env production
```

it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use rvmsudo and all to start your unicorn app server. You can do it

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -c /path/to/app/unicorn.rb -E production
```